# Snowflake - Strategy for loading multiple files with different formats

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 40 text files of different/inconsistent layouts. My end goal is to get this loaded to a consistent schema in our environment. Short of designing 40 load patterns, how can I best "dump" all of these into Snowflake on a recurring basis?  Once loaded I can more easily parse.  Does anyone have a good strategy on how to most easily do the "dump in into Snowflake" part?

Comment: Without more specifics I can only tell you "put everything in Snowflake and parse later"

Comment: It really depends on what are differences between those 40 "slightly" different formats, can you share more specifics?

Comment: We have different columns which represent the same data with different names/headings, we might have different data elements, etc.  It is all the same "Sales Transactions" type of data

hypothetical example:
file 1
vendor | product | date | vendor upc code | price
file 2
description | part # | date | qty | price
file 3
buyer email  | upc code  | price

Ultimately we can rename columns and have common elements from these, and union all.  Could use some thought leadership on getting the raw data loaded  without building 40 different tables and pipelines to load though. does that help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load data from a stage (file location) into a `STAGING` table using [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) with [load transformations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html).

To address your specific points:

- By specifying directory, snowflake will load all files in that directory
- I believe you can only load one type of [file format](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions) at a time.

Ex:

```sql
COPY INTO my_database.STAGING.foo (file_name, file_row_number, data)
FROM 
    's3://mybucket/sub_directory_name/'  -- Or other stage
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV)
;
```

Do note that CSV data represents a slightly difficult case with schema mismatch – your best solution is populate your staging table as a sparse matrix, the transform in downstream manipulations.